# Open Outlook from WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

what I am trying to do is I have a label and MouseLeftButtonDown Event on it when the user click on the label it open the outlook application but whenever click again it run into an Exception 
here is the code that I have `

```
if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mic = objOutlook.CreateItem (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
    mic.To = "someone@live.com";
    mic.Subject = "l";
    mic.Body = "h";
    mic.Display(true);
}
```

and here is the Exception that I got ![Com Exception][1]

[1]:

Comment: I put it as someone@live.com for privacy but, when I need to run the program I change it back to my support E-mail

Comment: Google for "outlook interop rpc_e_call_rejected" gives many results, e.g. [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2008/11/03/unable-to-instantiate-outlook-object-from-visual-studio-2008-on-vista-with-uac-on.aspx). What have you tried?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: How about `Process.Start(FilePathTo + "OUTLOOK.EXE");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that

```
var url = "mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=Test&body=Hello";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this will just open your default browser, not particularly Outlook.

Comment: Much better to open the default browser because maybe some users dont like to use outlook thank you

Comment: Do you know how I could change this to also include an attachment file? I've tried &attachment=" + filepath

Comment: @coder0815 : What if the `subject` or `body` contains the string `&`?